# Como marcar radio button dependiendo del valor traido desde BD

Tags: mysql, laravel

estos son mis radios button de mi formulario editar y el valor que guardo en mi bd es 1 o 2 este es el valor que me trae si es 1 o 2 intente de esta forma pero no me selecciona ningun valor y no se como hacer entonces $empleado->genero

```
{{ Form::label('status','Hombre',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
{{ Form::radio('status',$empleado->genero=='1','checked',false) }}
{{ Form::label('status','Mujer',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
{{ Form::radio('status',$empleado->genero=='2','checked',false) }}
```

y esta es mi consulta

```
$empleado = empleado::find($id);

return \View::make('empleado_editar', compact('paises','banco_id','dep_icf_id','puestos_id','actividades_id','gerencia_id','anos_consulta_id','municipio_honuras_id',
  'contratacion_id','nivel_academico', 'titulo_obtenido',
  'departamento_honduras','unidades_id', 'tipo_contratacion', 'anos_consulta', 'puesto', 'dep_icf', 'bancos','departamento_honuras_id'))->with([
    'empleado' => $empleado,
]);
```

lo intente de esta forma pero no me esta funcionando '

```
{{ Form::label('status','Hombre',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
{{ Form::radio('status',$genero=1,['id'=>'radio2'],false) }}
{{ Form::label('status','Mujer',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
{{ Form::radio('status',$genero=2,['id'=>'radio1'],false) }}
```

y este es el scrip

```
<script>
  if ('status',$empleado == "1") {
    $("#radio1").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("#radio2").prop("checked", true);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías realizar algo como esto

```
{{ Form::label('status','Hombre',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
@if ($empleado->genero=='1')
    {{ Form::radio('status','1',true) }}
@else
    {{ Form::radio('status','1') }}
@endif
{{ Form::label('status','Mujer',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
@if ($empleado->genero=='2')
    {{ Form::radio('status','2',true) }}
@else
    {{ Form::radio('status','2') }}
@endif
```

Según la documentación oficial de **Laravel** hay dos formas de usar `Form::radio`

1. `{{ Form::radio('name','value') }}`
2. `{{ Form::radio('name','value',true) }}` cuando necesitas que este en **checked**

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda me resulto muy bien me imagino que esto mismo debe ser para un checkbox el mismo procedimiento

Comment: Si correcto, para un Checkbox seria igual

Answer (score 0):

en la parte donde pintas tu formulario,suponiendo que usas la misma vista para insertar y modificar, tendrias que hacer un if para revisar si tiene valores devueltos o ponerle un valor por default

puedes usar una funcion

```
public function myMethod(Request $request){
  //2nd parameter means, if radio is not selected then use default value
  $radio = $request->get('radion_button', 0);
}
```

o bien puedes hacerlo en el mismo button

```
{{ Form::radio('tributary', 'true', @if ($station->tributary == true) true @else false @endif) }} Yes
```

Comment: ahi puse como lo intente pero no me esta funcionando no se por que

Answer (score 0):

utiliza un if para eso, seria algo como.

```
<pre><code>  if ('status',$empleado == "1") {
      $("#radio1").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("#radio2").prop("checked", true);
    }
```

este codigo esta en javascript, en php debe funcionarte igual, solo debes hacer el llamado de los radios por su "id".